# Bootloop with only bios screen showing

Tags: windows, windows-10, motherboard, bios

I got a BSOD (DPC watchdog violation), so I powered the system down

When I launched it again it got into a bootloop every 5-10 secs during of which the system would boot into BIOS with not a single piece of data showing and then restarting.

I have tried:

1. Reseated RAM
2. Removed HDD
3. Tried a diff PSU
4. Tried a diff CMOS battery
5. Finally bread boarding
6. Reset CMOS And booting with a usb

None of which worked.

- Mobo: GA-H81M-S2PH
- RAM: (single stick) DDR3 4GB
- CPU: pentium 4th gen G3220 (3.0 GHZ)
- HDD: Samsung (don't remember the rest)

I think something wiped the BIOS. My fans work just fine so it's not an overheat, the cables are all firmly placed and I tried most stuff in all sticky (s).

I think I have tried most of the bootloop fixer except a BIOS installation, trying another Mobo with same CPU and vice-versa, lastly I can't resort to buying a new hardware piece of any kind right now (low on budget).

Comment: I presume you have tried to run the win7 disk without a hard drive plugged in? Also reset the CMOS by shorting the pin on the motherboard?As taking out the battery won't always work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Many people will not read a huge bock of difficult to read text. Taking a minute to [edit] your question to make it easier to read will increase your chances of getting the help you seek.

Comment: In the edit the spaces are there charlieRB but when I save , goes back to old form , anyways , I can't get past the BIOS screen no matter what , I'll try shorting the CMOS

Comment: Nope, nothing from shorting my CMOS , tried booting with Linux mint , same old same old

Answer (score 0):

If it's a complete boot-loop of BIOS splash screen only and you cannot access BIOS setup, I'm sure it's a defective motherboard. I have gone the same thing on a Lenovo G400 laptop.

Comment: A defective mobo ..... that crossed my mind right after i got the bootloop, guess i take the worst case scenario for granted , but IF its only the bios then the problem can perhaps be fixed (warranty for mobo is long gone so i think i cant RMA it) anyways thanks for your opinion!

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, I have something in mind, maybe replacing the bios chip would be an option (not mine, because i can't do that). Give us an update whenever it got fixed.

Comment: Sure thing , im currently with a technician who's changing the bios , will reply as soon as possible

Answer (score -1):

Well , he said there was something wrong with the "capacitor" and said i should send it to Jigabyte , well i guess im gonna do that and since its Jigabyte i'll have to call this Question"Semi-Answered" , also i found out that i had 'bout 1 month left in my warranty 'lucky for once i guess' one last Question thou , its a Gamma Warranty, will they RMA it or just try to stick the mobo together untill the warranty ends?